# Как прочитать JSON значения отправленные WebHook

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть задача узнать сумму изменившегося баланса на кошельке. Я знаю что он приходит POST запросом но при попытке прочитать его выходит пустота.

Вот что сервер отправляет мне на условный payments.php

```
{
  "notification_id": "..."
  "delivery_attempt": 1,
  "created_at": 1426104819,
  "type": "address",
  "data": {
    "network": "BTC",
    "address": "3cBraN1Q...",
    "balance_change": "0.01000000", // net balance change, can be negative
    "amount_sent": "0.00000000",
    "amount_received": "0.01000000",
    "txid": "7af5cf9f2...", // the transaction's identifier (hash)
    "confirmations": X, // see below
    "is_green": false // legacy, can be ignored
  }
}
```

Далее мои жалкие попытки получить значение

```
require_once('classes/email.php');

if(isset($_POST)){

$data = json_decode($_POST, true);
$message = $data;

sendMessage('1207877606', $message, 'True', 'True');
}
```

Пробовал разные варианты но либо выдает
`[]` либо `array`

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема решена

```
require_once('classes/email.php');

if(isset($_POST)){

$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);
$message = $data['data']['address'];

sendMessage('1207877606', $message, 'True', 'True');
}
```